# finding the executing object

Tags: java, object

```
package assignment;
public class BankAccount {
private double balance; 
private String accountHolderName;

BankAccount()
{
    balance = 0;
    accountHolderName = "";
}
BankAccount(double balance, String accountHolderName)
{
    this.balance = balance;
    this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
}
public String withdrawal(double withdrawalAmount)
{
    String result = "";
    if(withdrawalAmount > balance)
    {
        result = "Account can not be overdrawn";
    }else if(withdrawalAmount <= 0)
    {
        result = "negative withdrawal amounts not allowed";
    }
    else
    {
        balance -= withdrawalAmount;
        result =  "$ " +withdrawalAmount + " withdrawn. Remaining balance is: " +balance;
    }
    return result;
}

public String deposit(double amountToDeposit)
{
    String result = "";
    if(amountToDeposit <= 0)
    {
        result = "Deposits must be positive";

    }else
    {
        balance += amountToDeposit;
        result = "$ " +amountToDeposit + " deposited. Balance is: " + balance;
    }
    return result;
}


public String transfer(double amountToTransfer,  BankAccount recipient)
{
    String result = "";
    recipient.withdrawal(amountToTransfer);
    recipient.deposit(amountToTransfer);
    result = recipient.withdrawal(amountToTransfer) +  "\n" +        recipient.deposit(amountToTransfer);;
    return result;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public String getAccountHolderName() {
    return accountHolderName;
}
public void setAccountHolderName(String accountHolderName) {
    this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BankAccount [balance=" + balance + ", accountHolderName="
            + accountHolderName + ", getBalance()=" + getBalance()
            + ", getAccountHolderName()=" + getAccountHolderName() + "]";
}


}
```

BankAccount person1 = new BankAccount(500, "Steve");

BankAccount person2 = new BankAccount(700, "Bob");

in the transfer method im stuck on how im supposed to transfer the money to person2.transfer(100,       person1);

i dont know how i would subtract 100 from the person2 object. thanks for the help

Comment: What is your problem? Is that task really that different to substracting in the `withdrawal` method that you can't solve your problem on your own?

Comment: Your question is most unclear and doesn't appear to have anything to do with your title. Objects don't execute, threads do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're inside a method ( transfer() ) of an object ( a BankAccount ) you are operationg on the bank account object. so you can reference the other variables and methods defined in that same object.

```
public void transfer(double amount, BankAccount recipient)
{
     if ( balance >= amount )
     {
        balance -= amount;
        //this balance variable represents the balance in the bank account 
        //object this money is coming from.
        recipient.balance += amount;
        //this balance variable is the balance of the recipient.
      }
}
```

That Said, Java Trails are really good. Try this one here. [Java Trails: Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html) will explain to you how objects work.

Comment: Thank for the help and the link really appreciate it!